# Error with using public static int (Windows Phone Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

On my Lumnia 930 my WinPhone app runs without any problem.
But from the store I get the message “Non compliant”.
I encircled the error. At the top of  MainPage() I set an integer value into a static variable in a static class. I did this very often in desktop programs (and in my own Lumnia-programs).
Why is this an error in the certification process?

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {  int maxItems;
       ...
        public MainPage()
        {  InitializeComponent();
           maxItems = 3;
           // the next line gives an error
           // without try/catch int SetGlobals the app closes silently
           SetGlobals(maxItems);
        }

        private void SetGlobals(int maxi)
        {   try
            {  Gl.maxItems = maxi;
        }
        catch 
        {  MessageBox.Show("Error in SetGlobals");
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: use `catch(Exception ex)` and get somehow `ex.Message` (or better `ex.ToString()`) to get more info on the exception you are getting

Comment: public static class Gl { public static int maxItems; ...}

Comment: I meant, replace the simple `catch` with a `catch(Exception ex)`, so you can know something about exception you got

Comment: Your simple but good tip helped. 
In the static class Gl I had a line
        public static TextWriter twI = new StreamWriter(“Set_Info.txt”);

This line is never used. VS 2013 didn't care about it. But the store did. I don't know why, but this was the error line (perhaps access rights).